# If $F= {\mathbb{Q}[x]}/{(x^5+5x^2-10)}$ then show that $[F:\mathbb{Q}]=5$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

If $F= {\mathbb{Q}[x]}/{(x^5+5x^2-10)}$ then show that $[F:\mathbb{Q}]=5$.

Now $f(x)=x^5+5x^2-10$ is $5$-Eisenstein, so irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ so by gauss lemma, also irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.  Now what will be the intermediate fields? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Just ignore if there is somebody gives you a downvote. By the way, I think $\{\overline{1},...,\overline{x^4}\}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $F$, since $\overline{x^5}=\overline{-5x^2+10}$.

Comment: @Mysterygirl Why $\overline{x^5}=\overline{-5x^2+10}$?

Comment: (Note that $\overline{x^5+5x^2-10}=\overline{0}$) ^^

Comment: @Mysterygirl yeah $\overline{x^5}=\overline{1.10+x.0-5x^2+x^3.0+x^4.0}$  So this is basically following from the dimension  of $F$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. We don't need find any intermediate fields

Comment: That's right. You can do the rest by yourself now. ^^

Comment: I guess you can think of $F$ is actually $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ where $\alpha $ is root of that polynomial hence degree of extension would be 5

Comment: @nozalp10 Yeah , $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \cong \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(f(x))}$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=5$

Comment: Its really a very bad question

Comment: To answer the question in the title you won't even need to know about the irreducibility of the quintic :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Tower Law . See **Dummit and Foote page 523** . If $L$ such that  $\Bbb{Q}\subseteq L\subseteq F$ be a subfield of $F$. Then $[F:\Bbb{Q}]=[F:L]\cdot [L:\Bbb{Q}]$ . Now as $5$ is a prime number , we have either $[F:L]=5\implies [L:\Bbb{Q}]=1\implies L=\Bbb{Q}$ or $[F:L]=1\implies L=F$ .

In all the cases above we are using the fact that if a subspace $W$ of a vector space $V$ has dimension equal , i.e if $\dim(W)=\dim(V)$ then $V=W$.

Proof that $[F:\Bbb{Q}]=5$.

Consider the polynomial $f(x)=x^{5}+5x^{2}-10\in \Bbb{Q}[x]$  and the quotient map $q:\Bbb{Q}[x]\to \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^5+5x^2-10)$ .

Then $q(x)=x\pmod{f(x)}$ and call this as $\bar{x}$. Now as $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ is an Euclidean Domain we have for any polynomial $g(x)\in\Bbb{Q}[x]$ , $g(x)=a(x)f(x)+r(x)$ for some $a(x),r(x)$ such that $\deg(r(x))<5$ .

It then follows that any element in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^5+5x^2-10)$ is of the form $r(x)\pmod {f(x)}$ with $\deg(r(x))<5$ as the quotient map is surjective.

This means that in the quotient we can represent any element by $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{4}a_{i}\bar{x}^{i}$ . Thus the set $\{1,\bar{x},...,\bar{x}^{4}\}$ is a spanning set for the vector space $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^5+5x^2-10)$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Now it only remains to prove that this set is linearly independent.

If possible let there exists $c_{0},...,c_{4}$ not all $0$ such that $c_{0}+c_{1}\bar{x}+...+c_{4}\bar{x}^{4}=0$ . This means that $f(x)$ must divide $c_{0}+c_{1}x+...+c_{4}x^{4}=0$ but this is impossible as $f(x)$ has degree $5$ and the above is of degree $4$. This means that the only possibility was that $c_{0}=c_{1}=...=c_{4}=0$.

Thus $\{1,\bar{x},...,\bar{x}^{4}\}$ is a linearly independent spanning set and hence a basis and thus $F$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$ has dimension $5$.

Comment: We have to show $ [F:\mathbb{Q}]=5$, We can't assume it

Comment: There is nothing to show there. I was answering your question about subextensions. The polynomial is irreducible as you correctly point out. So by definition itself $[F:\Bbb{Q}]=5$. This is because in the quotient $\{1,x,...,x^{4}\}$ forms a basis for $\frac{\Bbb{Q}[x]}{x^{5}+5x^{2}-10}$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$. A canonical isomorphism sends $x$ in the above field to a root of this polynomial which makes this field isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ . This directly tells you that $\{1,...,\alpha^{4}\}$ is a basis over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Okay I see why you might be confused. Wait I'll edit in a few more things.

Answer (score 1):

Since degree of extension is $5$ and the degree of subextension must divide $5$, the unique subextensions are the trivial ones